# find all columns of specified type in database

Tags: sql-server, database

I have SQL server 2008 R2. I want to get column name and table name where this columns is situated. And that i want to display for specified type. For example:
let's say i want to see all tinyint columns. The result should be the following:

```
ColumnName|TableName
orderID   |Orders
clientID  |Orders
refID     |discounts
```

Is it possible to write query to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the [`system`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260604%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) tables to get this data:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(c.OBJECT_ID) TableName
    , c.name ColumnName
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.types t 
    ON c.user_type_id=t.user_type_id
WHERE t.name = 'tinyint' 
ORDER BY c.OBJECT_ID;
```

Additional details on this can be found:

[SQL SERVER – 2005 – List All The Column With Specific Data Types](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/09/sql-server-2005-list-all-the-column-with-specific-data-types/)

Comment: Thank you. This query even outputs user defined functions that return specified type.

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
select ao.name objectname,ac.name columnname,t.name usertypename from sys.all_columns  ac inner join sys.types t
on ac.user_type_id  = t.user_type_id
inner join sys.all_objects ao
on ac.object_id = ao.object_id
and ao.type = 'U'
where t.name ='tinyint'
```